# Power Query - How to add up values of two different databases into one (online sales + instore sales = total sales)?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to add up the values of two different queries into one. To make it a bit simpler, it's like I have the online sales data and in-store sales data and I would like to add up the sales for each category.

For instance :

```
    Online sales
                    Apple  Orange Pineapple Grape
    January, 1, 2023    5   3   8   3
    January, 2, 2023    1   2   3   7
    January, 3, 2023    2   4   7   2
    January, 4, 2023    5   4   8   1
    January, 5, 2023    3   8   9   9
```

```
In-store sales
                    Apple  Orange Pineapple Grape
    January, 1, 2023    1   5   9   1
    January, 2, 2023    5   6   3   7
    January, 3, 2023    2   3   8   6
    January, 4, 2023    1   2   3   7
    January, 5, 2023    3   5   1   6
```

What I would like to have is something like this :

```
Total sales
                    Apple   Orange Pineapple Grape
    January, 1, 2023    6    8  17   4
    January, 2, 2023    6    8   6  14
    January, 3, 2023    4    7  15   8
    January, 4, 2023    6    6  11   8
    January, 5, 2023    6   13  10  15
```

In my original databases, I have way more columns and rows so it's almost impossible to do it manually.

Do you have any suggestions?

If you want, you can copy and paste this basic code in Power Query to have these two data sets.

Online sales :

```
#table({"Date", "Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Grape"},{
    {"January, 1, 2023", 5, 3, 8, 3},
    {"January, 2, 2023", 1, 2, 3, 7},
    {"January, 3, 2023", 2, 4, 7, 2},
    {"January, 4, 2023", 5, 4, 8, 1},
    {"January, 5, 2023", 3, 8, 9, 9}})
```

In-Store Sales :

```
#table({"Date", "Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Grape"},{
    {"January, 1, 2023", 1, 5, 9, 1},
    {"January, 2, 2023", 5, 6, 3, 7},
    {"January, 3, 2023", 2, 3, 8, 6},
    {"January, 4, 2023", 1, 2, 3, 7},
    {"January, 5, 2023", 3, 5, 1, 6}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot then repivot, so you don't have to adjust code based on number of columns

- Append the tables
- Right click the date column and unpivot other columns
- Click select the Attribute column, transform .. pivot column .. and use Value as the values

Sample code:

```
let Source = Table.Combine({#"Online Sales", #"In-Store Sales"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can append both the queries (Query1 & Query 2) and then apply group by like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't really use it because both of my original databases have nearly 400 columns so it would take so much time.